# Add Fields or Block to Lightbox overlay

Tags: entities, javascript

I am using Lightbox2 module for a view module effect. Works great! Could I Add fields(text) or a Block to the Lightbox overlay
?  It doesn't matter if its text field or a editable content block.

Example from MS Paint:

[image]

Comment: I believe Lightbox Trigger would work, but because the images are of one content type, individual descriptions would not be possible. hmmmmmm